# How to scale/move child images in a container relative to scaling of father image in container?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a father-image in a container and several clickable icons on top of that image with an absolute position.

I now want to scale the father-image to max-width: 100%

Now I want that the icons that are placed with absolute position to behave relative in accordance to the father-image so that they are always at the same spot on the father image.

Here is my code so far:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.father-image {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.icon_pos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.icon {
  width: 20em;
  height: 5em;
  background: url("icon.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 20em;
  display: fill;
}

.icon:hover {
  width: 20em;
  height: 5em;
  background: url("icon_hover.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="father-image" src="father-image.png">

  <div class="icon_pos">
    <a href="SOME_LINK">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works as expected. The father-image is displayed and the icon is the position 50/50 and is clickable.

No I want to scale the father-image to 100% (adding 'max-width: 100%' to class 'father-image'). If I do so the image is fully visible on the screen but the icon remain at 50/50 which is not the needed behavior since it should also move/scale relative to the father image.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you just have to set ".icon_pos" position to % of ".container"

```
.icon_pos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
```

## update 1

this will change your container "icon_pos" width and height based on ".container"

```
.icon_pos 
{
      position: absolute;
      top: 5%;
      left: 5%;
      width: 20%;
      height: 20%;
 }
```

you should also set your icon size to 100% of "icon_pos"

```
.icon 
{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This solves the positioning problem but the icons stay the same size. Do you have an idea on how to scale the icons as well?

Comment: try do add width and height to icon_pos